# How to VBA catch request timeout error?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, timeout

I'm using object [MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278%28v=vs.85%29) send request to webservice; with this object, I can speed up data loading by **asynchronous** method and avoid lockups Excel screen (*not responding*). But, I'm still have a problem when webservice response for a long time, out of ServerXMLHTTP60 timeout setting, the request function was silently, I cannot catch timeout error. At [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407010/how-to-vba-callback-function-when-xmlhttp-ontimeout), @osknows suggests using `xmlhttp status = 408` to catching timeout error, but it doesn't work for me.

I've prepaired a test file, you can download [at here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60740207/testTimeout.xlsm). Open VBA source by press `Atl + F8`, you will see class module `CXMLHTTPHandler`, that I copied from [this guide](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/)

```
    If m_xmlHttp.readyState = 4 Then
        If m_xmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
            MsgBox m_xmlHttp.responseText
        ElseIf m_xmlHttp.Status = 408 Then 'Debug never run to here?
            MsgBox "Request timeout"
        Else
         'Error happened
        End If
    End If
```

**How to VBA catch request timeout error?**

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are several complications here.

1. `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` does not expose COM-usable events. Therefore it is not easily possible to instantiate an object using `WithEvents` and attach to its `OnReadyStateChange` event.
   The event is there, but the standard VBA way to handle it does not work.
2. The module that could handle the event cannot be created using the VBA IDE.
3. You need to call [`waitForResponse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765535%28v=vs.85%29) when you use asynchronous requests (additionally to calling `setTimeouts()`!)
4. There is no `timeout` event. Timeouts are thrown as an error.

**To resolve issue #1:**

Usually a VBA class module (also applies to user forms or worksheet modules) allows you to do this:

```vb
Private WithEvents m_xhr As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
```

so you can define an event handler like this:

```vb
Private Sub m_xhr_OnReadyStateChange()
  ' ...
End Sub
```

Not so with `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`. Doing this will result in a Microsoft Visual Basic Compile Error: "Object does not source automation events".

Apparently the event is not exported for COM use. There is a way around this.

The signature for `onreadystatechange` reads

```vb
Property onreadystatechange As Object
```

So you can assign an object. We could create a class module with an `onreadystatechange` method and assign like this:

```vb
m_xhr.onreadystatechange = eventHandlingObject
```

However, this does not work. `onreadystatechange` expects an object and whenever the event fires, the object *itself* is called, not the method we've defined. (For the `ServerXMLHTTP` instance there is no way of knowing which method of the user-defined `eventHandlingObject` we intend to use as the event handler).

We need a callable object, i.e. an object with a *default method* (every COM object can have exactly one).
*(For example: `Collection` objects are callable, you can say `myCollection("foo")` which is a shorthand for `myCollection.Item("foo")`.)*

**To resolve issue #2:**

We need a class module with a default property. Unfortunately these can't be created using the VBA IDE, but you can create them using a text editor.

- prepare the class module that contains an `onreadystatechange` function in the VBA IDE
- export it to a `.cls` file via right click
- open that in a text editor and add the following line beneath the `onreadystatechange` signature:
  `Attribute OnReadyStateChange.VB_UserMemId = 0`
- remove the original class module and and re-import it from file.

This will mark the modified method as `Default`. You can see a little blue dot in the Object Browser (F2), which marks the default method:

[image: Default Method]

So every time the object is called, *actually* the `OnReadyStateChange` method is called.

**To resolve issue #3:**

Simply call `waitForResponse()` after `send()`.

```vb
m_xhr.Send
m_xhr.waitForResponse timeout
```

In case of a timeout: If you did not call this method, the request simply never returns. If you did, an error is thrown after `timeout` milliseconds.

**To resolve issue #4:**

We need to use an `On Error` handler that catches the timeout error and transforms it into an event, for convenience.

**Putting it all together**

Here is a VB class module I wrote that wraps and handles an `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` object. Save it as `AjaxRequest.cls` and import it into your project:

```vb
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "AjaxRequest"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private m_xhr As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Attribute m_xhr.VB_VarHelpID = -1
Private m_isRunning As Boolean

' default timeouts. TIMEOUT_RECEIVE can be overridden in request
Private Const TIMEOUT_RESOLVE As Long = 1000
Private Const TIMEOUT_CONNECT As Long = 1000
Private Const TIMEOUT_SEND As Long = 10000
Private Const TIMEOUT_RECEIVE As Long = 30000

Public Event Started()
Public Event Stopped()
Public Event Success(data As String, serverStatus As String)
Public Event Error(data As String, serverStatus As String, xhr As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP)
Public Event TimedOut(message As String)

Private Enum ReadyState
  XHR_UNINITIALIZED = 0
  XHR_LOADING = 1
  XHR_LOADED = 2
  XHR_INTERACTIVE = 3
  XHR_COMPLETED = 4
End Enum

Public Sub Class_Terminate()
  Me.Cancel
End Sub

Public Property Get IsRunning() As Boolean
  IsRunning = m_isRunning
End Property

Public Sub Cancel()
  If m_isRunning Then
    m_xhr.abort
    m_isRunning = False
    RaiseEvent Stopped
  End If
  Set m_xhr = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub HttpGet(url As String, Optional timeout As Long = TIMEOUT_RECEIVE)
  Send "GET", url, vbNullString, timeout
End Sub

Public Sub HttpPost(url As String, data As String, Optional timeout As Long = TIMEOUT_RECEIVE)
  Send "POST", url, data, timeout
End Sub

Private Sub Send(method As String, url As String, data As String, Optional timeout As Long)
  On Error GoTo HTTP_error

  If m_isRunning Then
    Me.Cancel
  End If

  RaiseEvent Started

  Set m_xhr = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

  m_xhr.OnReadyStateChange = Me
  m_xhr.setTimeouts TIMEOUT_RESOLVE, TIMEOUT_CONNECT, TIMEOUT_SEND, timeout

  m_isRunning = True
  m_xhr.Open method, url, True
  m_xhr.Send data
  m_xhr.waitForResponse timeout

  Exit Sub

HTTP_error:
  If Err.Number = &H80072EE2 Then
    Err.Clear
    Me.Cancel
    RaiseEvent TimedOut("Request timed out after " & timeout & "ms.")
    Resume Next
  Else
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
  End If
End Sub

' Note: the default method must be public or it won't be recognized
Public Sub OnReadyStateChange()
Attribute OnReadyStateChange.VB_UserMemId = 0
  If m_xhr.ReadyState = ReadyState.XHR_COMPLETED Then
    m_isRunning = False
    RaiseEvent Stopped

    ' TODO implement 301/302 redirect support

    If m_xhr.Status >= 200 And m_xhr.Status < 300 Then
      RaiseEvent Success(m_xhr.responseText, m_xhr.Status)
    Else
      RaiseEvent Error(m_xhr.responseText, m_xhr.Status, m_xhr)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Note the line `m_xhr.OnReadyStateChange = Me`, which assigns the AjaxRequest instance *itself* as the event handler, as made possible by marking `OnReadyStateChange()` as the default method.

**Be aware that** if you make changes to `OnReadyStateChange()` you need to go through the export/modify/re-import routine again since the VBA IDE does not save the "default method" attribute.

The class exposes the following interface

- Methods:

  - `HttpGet(url As String, [timeout As Long])`
  - `HttpPost(url As String, data As String, [timeout As Long])`
  - `Cancel()`
- Properties

  - `IsRunning As Boolean`
- Events

  - `Started()`
  - `Stopped()`
  - `Success(data As String, serverStatus As String)`
  - `Error(data As String, serverStatus As String, xhr As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP)`
  - `TimedOut(message As String)`

Use it in another class module, for example in a user form, with `WithEvents`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents ajax As AjaxRequest

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Set ajax = New AjaxRequest
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Me.TextBox2.Value = ""

  If ajax.IsRunning Then
    ajax.Cancel
  Else
    ajax.HttpGet Me.TextBox1.Value, 1000
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub ajax_Started()
  Me.Label1.Caption = "Running" & Chr(133)
  Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Cancel"
End Sub

Private Sub ajax_Stopped()
  Me.Label1.Caption = "Done."
  Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Send Request"
End Sub

Private Sub ajax_TimedOut(message As String)
  Me.Label1.Caption = message
End Sub

Private Sub ajax_Success(data As String, serverStatus As String)
  Me.TextBox2.Value = serverStatus & vbNewLine & data
End Sub

Private Sub ajax_Error(data As String, serverStatus As String, xhr As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP)
  Me.TextBox2.Value = serverStatus
End Sub
```

Make enhancements as you see fit. The `AjaxRequest` class was merely a byproduct of answering this question.

Comment: FWIW: Probably it would have been easier to use a `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest` object instead of banging on `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`. `WinHttpRequest` exposes all the right events in the right fashion, but there you go.

Comment: Thank you so much! Recent day, I'm stress with some another tasks, then I've still checked this question; today I'm very happy with your answer; It is very detailed. I will try it in early tomorow morning. Now is very late night

Comment: @Davuz That's all-right. I did not want to push you, but I was starting to wonder if you respond at all. Maybe I was too impatient. ;)

Comment: :D Oh,I mean I'm too busy so `forget` to check answer. Now I'm trying it

Comment: `AjaxRequest` run perfectly! Thank you again!